# Chrome doesn't prompt for client certificate

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, authentication, ssl, client

I've been trying to setup client certificate authentication for almost three days now but to no avail.

I've signed up for a free domain at heliohost and have installed a free ssl certificate issued by Let's encrypt.

My plan is to have self signed certificates and check them against the database later(for user authentication) therefore I set my `SSLVerifyClient` to `optional_no_ca` in the htaccess file. I installed several self signed certificates generated by openssl but no matter which browser I try(Chrome, Firefox or IE) I get no prompts to choose a certificate **except** when i tried to access it on my phone via Chrome, in this case it offers to install a certificate since I don't have any on the phone.

This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
SSLRequireSSL
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
```

I would really appreciate any feedback pertaining the issue, this is my first time trying to implement this and I'm not sure weather the issue is with my setup or chrome.

also I'm using chrome 59

Kriss

Comment: So how did you install the client certificate in the browser?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I installed it via a pkcs12 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to chrome, I have unfortunately not been able to pinpoint it but managed to get it working and prompting me for the certificate on firefox.
Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted the part of the ssl certificate authorities configuration. it is needed to configure the CA certificate that signs your client certificates ( see [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients)

```
 SSLCACertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/ca.crt"
```

The server is not sending the root CA, then since you have set SSLVerifyClient to optional_no_ca, the browser automatically performs the connection because it can not find any suitable certificate (see below TLS1.2 note)

Since you have set `optional_no_ca` in your server, it accepts the connection even if no certificate is presented. It you set `require` you will find that the connection fails with Chrome.

`SSLCACertificateFile` is not configurable in .htaccess. Since you can not customize chrome, i am afraid you need to configure this parameter to force certificate prompt

---

When the certificate list is empty, the behavior between browsers may vary because the TLS specification allows it

See [TLS1.2 RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt)

> **7.4.4.  Certificate Request**
>
> certificate_authorities
>
> A list of the distinguished names [X501] of acceptable
>         certificate_authorities, represented in DER-encoded format.  These
>         distinguished names may specify a desired distinguished name for a
>         root CA or for a subordinate CA; thus, this message can be used to
>         describe known roots as well as a desired authorization space.  **If
>         the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY
>         send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType**,
>         unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.
>
> **7.4.6.  Client Certificate**
>
> [...] 
>   **If the client does not send any certificates, the
>         server MAY at its discretion either continue the handshake without
>         client authentication, or respond with a fatal handshake_failure
>         alert.**

Comment: I understand, however the issue was mostly due to chrome and there's also the issue that I cannot add the SSLCACertificateFile since it can only be added in the server config file but I only have access to .htaccess. I've got it to work in firefox with self singed certificates.

Comment: You will need to configure `SSLCACertificateFile` in main config. See updated answer